# Azure AD integration with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory

Our applications are deployed on Google App Engine and now our clients wants us to authenticate through their Azure Active Directory authentication service. GAE only provides 'Google Accounts API' and 'Google Apps domain'  How to integrate GAE with Azure AD authentication? Any inputs will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft according to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/google/googleappengine/ has integrated Azure Active Directory with App Engine . I don't see how that page or the links from it explain exactly how to do use that integration, but that may be because I don't have an account on that site (nor do I intend to make one), and *with* such an account you should be better placed to study MS's docs or ask them directly.

Comment: Thank you! probably a great idea to ask MS.  Although I do not want to switch to Azure having been a GAE user, but when it comes to support,  may be MS does better job. Let me see...

Comment: Hmm I have looked at it, there just isn't any information on their site about what the connector could do.  My guess is they act as an openid or outh2 provider.